# jQuery cookie plugin - save and call parsetInt() values

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new to JS. I have a script which should count clicks and store clicks number value in cookie. The problem is I can't correctly save and call clicks number(generated by parseInt) value from cookies.

Here is the code http://jsfiddle.net/csTpG/99/ (using jquery.cookie plugin)

```js
$('#counter').click(function() {
  var productID = $(this).attr('name');
  var $this = $(this);
  $.get('/', {
    item_id: productID
  }, function(response) {
    if (response) {
      if (response == 'empty')
        $this.text('Count');
      else
        $this.text('Count (' + parseInt(response) + ')');
      $.cookie('clicked-counter', 'true');
    }
  });
  return false;
});

if ($.cookie('clicked-counter') == 'true') {
  var cookie = $.cookie('clicked-counter');
  $('#counter a').text('Count (' + cookie + ')');
};
```

```css
#counter{background-color:white}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="counter">Counter</button>
```

Yup parseInt() shows NaN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated your script to make it work (i included jQuery.cookie plugin for example) , look here http://jsfiddle.net/nicolapeluchetti/csTpG/100/ but there are still some issues. You get NaN when you do a parseInt because you are trying to parse an html page that returns from your ajax call. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Im sending url to server via .get() (with item_id). And server gives me total number of item_ids wich were sent. This works fine, but i cant understand how to save parseInt value in cookie and how get it back after.
Your solution gives me back 'true' value from cookies, but not parseInt data.

Comment: @Toon that is because you are calling an url on jsfiddle that returns a webPage. it will never work there i think.

Comment: the question is how to save parseInt() data in cookies. I guess i need edit this line $.cookie('clicked-counter', 'true' ); and put parseInt value instead 'true'

Comment: @toon yes you should do that, i'm sorry bu the question wasn't clear! and you use `$.cookie('clicked-counter')` to retrieve the value

Comment: any idea what should i write instead of 'true'?

Comment: as you stated you should save `parseInt()` return value. look at this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/nicolapeluchetti/csTpG/102/ and to this: click on the counter and then reload the page, you will have saved the cookie